# Difference between data replication and cache

Tags: caching, server, distributed-computing

What is the difference between cache as a pull data model vs data replication as a push data model? I don't know the difference

Answer (score 2):

Cache is usually filled in on demand, when you have a data miss, thus pull. 
Data replication is usually accomplished by actively propagating data to replica nodes, thus push.